# Sql Search based on condtions

Tags: sql-server

This picture shows Two tables named Documents & Reference.

[image: picture]

And a particular record of Document have multiple References and the references are been duplicated in other records of documents.

I have tried RECURSIVE Method of SQL CTE but not getting the desired output.

Following are the required result:

When Search Reference No like “Aaa11”

- it should first get DocID and References linked to that DocID.

For example for DocID 1, the reference will be based on search Aaa11, Aaa12, Aaa13. As Aaa1 is found based on search, now it should take remaining 2 references and search those references in other documents,

for example it will than search for Aaa13 which appears in DocID 2, now then it will take all reference of DocID 2 like Bbb12, Bbc11 and Aaa13.

As Aaa13 is matched from search now it will again search for remaining Reference Numbers like Bbb12 & Bbc11.

And we see that we can found record Bbb12 in DocID 3. It will go with looping until E of References.

And the result will be than

DocID, reference No.

Here is the Piece of code for CTE that i have tried but it is not fetching any record:

```html
WITH  DocumentsAndTheirReferences
  (DocID,
  Ref
  )
  
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT Reference.DocID,Reference.Ref
FROM Reference  

UNION ALL

SELECT DocumentsAndTheirReferences.DocID,DocumentsAndTheirReferences.Ref
FROM DocumentsAndTheirReferences 
JOIN Reference ON DocumentsAndTheirReferences.DocID = Reference.DocID  
WHERE DocumentsAndTheirReferences.DocID > 1

 UNION ALL
 
SELECT  DocumentsAndTheirReferences.DocID, DocumentsAndTheirReferences.Ref  FROM DocumentsAndTheirReferences JOIN Reference ON DocumentsAndTheirReferences.DocID = Reference.DocID
WHERE Reference.DocID LIKE DocumentsAndTheirReferences.DocID
 )
SELECT * FROM DocumentsAndTheirReferences WHERE Ref LIKE '111aa'
ORDER BY DocumentsAndTheirReferences.DocID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: It would be perfect if you could share a DDL script for the sample case

Comment: Show us your recursive CTE either.

Comment: @Arvo now you can find my above attached code that i used but not getting any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sami, not with CTE but using a WHILE loop I could create following SQL Script
Could you pleae test is if it is OK for you

Please note that I did not populate the sample tables with all data, so please test the script on your own tables with your own sample data

```
/*
    create table Documents (
        DocID int identity(1,1),
        Name varchar(10),
        Des varchar(10)
    )

    insert into Documents select 'Abc','2222'
    insert into Documents select 'Xyz','3333'
    insert into Documents select 'Ghi','4444'
    insert into Documents select 'Lmn','5555'
    insert into Documents select 'Pqr','6666'
    insert into Documents select 'Uwe','7777'

    create table Reference (
        RefID int identity(1,1),
        DocID int,
        RefNo varchar(10)
    )
insert into Reference select 1,'Aaa11'
insert into Reference select 1,'Aaa12'
insert into Reference select 1,'Aaa13'

insert into Reference select 2,'Bbb12'
insert into Reference select 2,'Bbc11'
insert into Reference select 2,'Aaa13'


insert into Reference select 3,'Ccc11'
insert into Reference select 3,'Ccd12'
insert into Reference select 3,'Bbb12'

insert into Reference select 4,'Ddd11'
insert into Reference select 4,'Ddd12'
insert into Reference select 4,'Ccd12'

insert into Reference select 5,'Rrr11'
insert into Reference select 5,'Rrg12'
insert into Reference select 5,'Ddd12'

insert into Reference select 6,'Aab12'
insert into Reference select 6,'Ssb11'
insert into Reference select 6,'Ffg13'
    */

    if object_id('tempdb..#Ref','U') is not null
        drop table #Ref

    declare @cnt int
    declare @ref varchar(10) = 'Aaa11'
    select RefID, DocID, RefNo into #Ref from Reference where refno = @ref
    set @cnt = @@rowcount

    while @cnt > 0
    begin
    set identity_insert #Ref on

    insert into #Ref (RefID, DocID, RefNo)
    select r.RefID, r.DocID, r.RefNo
    from Reference r
    inner join #Ref 
        on #Ref.DocID = r.DocID  
    where r.RefID not in (select RefID from #Ref )

    set @cnt = @@rowcount
    if @cnt > 0
    begin

        insert into #Ref (RefID, DocID, RefNo)
        select r.RefID, r.DocID, r.RefNo
        from Reference r
        inner join #Ref 
            on #Ref.RefNo = r.RefNo  
        where r.RefID not in (select RefID from #Ref )

        set @cnt = @@rowcount

    end

    end
    set identity_insert #Ref off

    select * from #Ref order by RefId
```

For variable value 'Aaa11', the output is as follows

[image]

Actually for most values the output is the same, only the group 6 rows are seperated from others. When you use a value from Group 6, you only get those 3 rows in the resultset

Comment: The recursive cte would be a much better approach than a while loop for this.

Comment: @Eralper Hello Sir, your piece of code is not fetching any record either .

Comment: @SeanLange Hello Sir, Can you please look at the code ofv RECURSIVE CTE i have attached above in my post. any help would be great full and would be appreciated.

Comment: @Sean, I worked on recursive CTE option but I realized that I had to refer to the same CTE expression in WHERE clause of the forming SELECTs of the CTE itself which is not allowed. So I had to switch to another solution like this WHILE loop

Comment: @Sami, I tested and seemed to be working for my data. Could you please tell more about how tou tested

Comment: @Eralper Sir i have tried the same code you posted here, but for me it not getting any record but when i deleted the WHERE CLAUSE it will then show all the references found in Reference table.

Comment: @Sami, I added the sample data script you have shared with us in the screenshot, and when I execute using this data I got 15 rows in the resultset.

Comment: @Eralper Sir i am trying the same code you posted but it is not fetching any result can you please look at the another answer i have posted below

Comment: @Eralper Yes Sir, Thank you so much it worked for me now. Can you please provide me your contact details so that i cant understand the logic behind your code. Like if you dont mind and have much time to cooperate with me .

Answer (score 0):

```html
DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(255)
SET @Search ='112aa'

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
 Reference.DocID AS DocID  FROM Reference 
INNER JOIN Documents o ON
  Reference.DocID = o.ID

WHERE (Ref) LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' 
) X

LEFT JOIN Reference ON Reference.DocID = X.DocID
```

Here is the another Way of getting the Duplicated Records from References based on any Particular RefNo. It will fetch the DocID and their References. But still from this Output i want to perform another search on this result to find more duplication of References.